# click on slider image to do a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wowslider

I am using wowslider for my slideshow. i would like to execute a function when a click is made on a particular image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body style="background-color:transparent;margin:auto">


<div id="wowslider-container1">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
    <li><img src="data1/images/1.jpg" alt="1" title="1" id="wows1_0"/></li>

    <li><img src="data1/images/2.jpg" alt="2" title="2" id="wows1_2" ondblclick="show()" /></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/3.jpg" alt="3" title="3" id="wows1_3"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/4.jpg" alt="4" title="4" id="wows1_4"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/5.jpg" alt="5" title="5" id="wows1_5"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/6.jpg" alt="6" title="6" id="wows1_6"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/7.jpg" alt="7" title="7" id="wows1_7"/></li>

</ul></div>
<div class="ws_thumbs">
```

```
</div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function show() {
    window.alert("checked");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my code. i tried it by  adding the doube click attribute on the image. But it is not working. Suggestions are highly appreciated. thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you pls share jsfiddle for you code.

Comment: sorry am completely new to this environment. what does that mean ? jsfiddle ?

Comment: Have you tried to call the function when the `<li>` is clicked what in you case should be the same as clicking on the image?

Comment: @kishore with http://jsfiddle.net/ you can share your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kishoreavails/3uo0cm5s/ jsfidde @PushkerYadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to your image id:

```
$('#wows1_2').click(show); // show is your function
```

or:

```
$('#wows1_2').click(function(){ //do something here });
```

Comment: where to add this line? @chris

Comment: add it anywhere in you html file, do it this way to be sure the html has been loaded: $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#wows1_2').click(show);
});